# Why is there "ringing" at the violet end of a rainbow but not the red end?

Tags: optics

I've recently noticed that if you look closely at the violet end of a rainbow, you can see a sort of "ringing" effect where there are alternating bands of color and lack of color. You can apparently photograph this:

[image: upload.wikimedia.org]

Zoom in closely to the violet end of the rainbow to see it.

What causes this? And why doesn't the same effect produce "ringing" on the red side of the rainbow?

Comment: I see: Before violet it looks to me like the rainbow colors blend into the background colors. After violet the rainbow stops. Could you elaborate on what seems weird?

Comment: @NeuroFuzzy If you look after the violet band, you can see a faint green band, then another violet band, then what looks like a really faint green band again. I'm guessing this has something to do with constructive or destructive interference, but I have no idea what.

Comment: Oh towards the center of it! I was looking at either end.

Comment: @NeuroFuzzy I guess it would be toward the center of the "net" rainbow, but it's toward the end of the "traditional" ROYGBIV rainbow.

Comment: "The very existence of supernumerary rainbows was historically a first indication of the wave nature of light, and the first explanation was provided by Thomas Young in 1804.[34]"[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow#Supernumerary_rainbow)

Comment: Thanks! I came across that, but I still don't get why that would cause the effect to only be present at the violet end or why it seems to alternate between green and violet at that point.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow#Supernumerary_rainbow

Comment: @FabriceNEYRET Thanks for the link! I've already read this but still don't fully understand what causes that or why it's only on the violet side of the rainbow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On rainbow formation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow#Supernumerary_rainbow . See a bit more about supernumeraries here http://www.atoptics.co.uk/rainbows/supers.htm, and http://www.atoptics.co.uk/rainbows/supers.htm .

Classical rainbow is explained by geometric optics, which applies on big enough droplets. When these approach the scale of light wavelength, geometric optic get less and less valid, replaced by wave optics. Smallest droplets lies at the limit, giving the quite complicated Mie scattering profile https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mie_scattering

Look as this nasty profile - and it's a log plot ! ( The 2 lobes at 180 +- 40° are the classical geometry rainbow. )

[image]

As a wave diffraction effects it oscillates, through interference bands that are very wavelength-dependant and thus appear colored. On general clouds are made of drops having different sizes, which tend to blur out these oscillations at averaging. But when droplets do have quite the same size, then the oscillation stands and show as the supernumerary.